# Web2py when deployed on Pythonanywhere not automatically picking up views for function

Tags: python, web2py, pythonanywhere

I am new to web2py but it has made me curious. Today i tried making a simple function in default.py

say testFunction()

on local host the  `url <localhost>TestApplication/default/testFunction` worked but after deployment to pythonanywhere  it showed me error **invalid view (default/testFunction.html)**

I figured that its not getting a view for testFunction() so i made a default/testFunction.htm in views and then it worked.

My question is why cant web2py pick up the default view for my function if its not there,When deployed? How can i make it do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is by [design](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core):

> If a view is not found, web2py tries to use a generic view. By default, generic views are disabled, although the 'welcome' app includes a line in /models/db.py to enable them on localhost only. They can be enabled per extension type and per action (using response.generic_patterns). In general, generic views are a development tool and typically should not be used in production. If you want some actions to use a generic view, list those actions in response.generic_patterns (discussed in [more detail](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#Generic-views) in the chapter on Services).

Comment: I was wondering the same as @amar - glad I found this thread.  Thanks!